# Равенство векторов на плоскости

Tags: ооп, классы

Описать класс вектор на плоскости, содержащий поля: координаты вектора и 
методы: вывода координат на экран, нахождения угла, образованного вектором с осью ОХ, сравнение вектора на равенство с вектором, заданным в качестве параметра.

Не получается проверить на равенство векторы. Код прилагаю. Метод для проверки равенства называется isEqual.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

class pVector
{
private: double x, y;
public:

    // 1) конструктор для создания вектора с нулевыми координатами
    pVector()
    {
        x = 0.0;
        y = 0.0;
    }

    // 2) конструктор с двумя параметрами для создания вектора
    pVector(double x_, double y_)
    {
        x = x_;
        y = y_;
    }
    // 3) конструктор, в который передаются координаты двух точек
    pVector(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)
    {
        x = x2 - x1;
        y = y2 - y1;
    }
    // Метод. Вывод координат
    void printCoordinates()
    {
        cout << "Координаты вектора: x = " << x <<", y = " << y << endl;
    }

    // Метод. Угол в градусах между вектором и осью OX;
    double getAngle()
    {
        if(x == 0.0 && y == 0.0) return 0.0;

        if(x == 0.0) {
            if(y > 0)
                return 90;
            else
                return 270;
        }

        if(y == 0) {
            if(x > 0)
                return 0;
            else
                return 180;
        }
        const double pi=3.14159;
        if(x > 0 && y > 0)
            return atan(y / x) * (180.0 / pi);
        if(x < 0 && y > 0)
            return 180 - atan(y / -x) * (180.0 / pi);
        if(x < 0 && y < 0)
            return 180 + atan(y / x) * (180.0 / pi);
        if(x > 0 && y < 0)
            return 360 - atan(-y / x) * (180.0 / pi);
    }
        // Метод равенство векторов
        int isEqual(pVector v)
    {
        int t; int c; double x1; double y1; double x2; double y2;
        t=sqrt(pow(x1,2)+pow(y1,2));
        c=sqrt(pow(x2,2)+pow(y2,2));
        if (c==t)
        cout<<"Вектора равны ";
        else cout<<"Вектора не равны";
    }

};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    pVector v1;
    pVector v2(15, 4);
    pVector v3(-3, -1, 8, 19);
    pVector v4(2, 8, 17, 12); // координаты этого вектора равны вектору v2!
    pVector v5(-5, 5);
    cout << "Координаты векторов: " << endl;
    v1.printCoordinates();
    v2.printCoordinates();
    v3.printCoordinates();
    v4.printCoordinates();
    v5.printCoordinates();
    getch();
    cout << "\nУглы между вектором и осью Ох: "<< endl;
    cout << "v1 Угол: " << v1.getAngle() << endl;
    cout << "v2 Угол: " << v2.getAngle() << endl;
    cout << "v3 Угол: " << v3.getAngle() << endl;
    cout << "v4 Угол: " << v4.getAngle() << endl;
    cout << "v5 Угол: " << v5.getAngle() << endl;
    getch();
    cout << "\nРавенство векторов: " << endl;
    cout << "  " << v2.isEqual(v1) << endl;
    cout << "  " << v2.isEqual(v2) << endl;
    cout << "  " << v2.isEqual(v3) << endl;
    cout << "  " << v2.isEqual(v4) << endl;
    cout << "  " << v2.isEqual(v5) << endl;

    getch(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Векторы равны, если их соответствующие координаты равны.*

```
int isEqual(pVector v)
{
    int t; int c; double x1; double y1; double x2; double y2;
    // 1. откуда берутся значения x1, y1, x2, y2?
    // 2. почему результат вычислений с плавающей точкой превращается в целое?
    t=sqrt(pow(x1,2)+pow(y1,2));
    c=sqrt(pow(x2,2)+pow(y2,2));
    if (c==t)
    cout<<"Вектора равны ";
    else cout<<"Вектора не равны";
}
```

Правильно:

```
bool isEqual(pVector v)
{
  return x == v.x && y == v.y;
}
```

Comment: Векторы равны, если их можно совместить параллельным переносом.

Comment: @Эникейщик Здорово. Это отличается от того, что я написал?

Comment: А вы сами не видите? У равных векторов совсем необязательно равные координаты.

Comment: @Эникейщик Cпасибо, достаточно. Это какой-то другой, неевклидовый мир.

Comment: <зануда> вектор - класс (!) объектов. Соответственно этот код вообще к нему не относится) А если фиксировать представителя, то всё в порядке. @Эникейщик

Comment: @Эникейщик, не путайте вектор с отрезком. Вектор на плоскости задается 2 числами (координатами). Это могут быть, например, направление и длина. Если два объекта движутся в одинаковом направлении с одинаковой (по модулю) скоростью, значит их вектора скоростей равны, и не важно в каком месте находится каждый из объектов.

Comment: @Эникейщик, на самом деле это просто 2 эквивалентных друг другу определения равенства векторов - с точки зрения геометрии (через параллельный перенос) и с точки зрения линейной алгебры (через равенство координат).

Comment: @insolor Ok, так понятно.